# Append to an array made from ul

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Hi im trying to append a "s" to each element an array created from a unsorted list. Here is my code and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Html:

```
<ul>
    <li class="fruit">Apple</li>
    <li class="fruit">Banana</li>
    <li class="fruit">Pineapple</li>
    <li class="fruit">Orange</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript to append s to each element

```
var list = document.getElementByClassName('friut');
for(var i=0;i < list.length; i++) {
    var arrValue = list[i];
    list[i] = arrValue.innerHTML + 's';

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you misspelled both `getElementsByClassName` and "fruit".  If all you are trying to do is make an array of strings equal to the list elements' values + "s", that's your problem.

If you're trying to actually add 's's to the HTML, you want something like this:

```
for(var i=0;i < list.length; i++) {
      list[i].innerHTML += 's';
}
```

Comment: You might want to explain the difference between over-writing (`innerHTML = 's'`) and appending (`innerHTML += 's')`.

Answer (score 1):

It's getElementsbyClassName, not getElementByClassName. You also spelled 'fruit' as 'friut'

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('fruit');
for(var i=0;i < list.length; i++) {
    var arrValue = list[i];
    list[i] = arrValue.innerHTML + 's';
}
```